# Entity Data Model Wizard crashes

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am using Windows 10 with VS 2015. Currently, I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 project with entity framework 6.0.0.0 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 4.122.1.0. Each time I tried to use Entity Data Model wizard to generate the model, it crashes when I select data connection and NEXT. Any idea? Thanks.
[ScreenShot Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh6o7.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. Using `Nuget` Package Manager, install `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`
2. Download the `.msi` of that package
3. Install it, and that is all